# Making files with map or scenario information, such as what resources to load, objects, locations, events

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directx

I'm making a simple graphics engine in C++, using Visual C++ and DirectX, and I'm testing out different map layouts.
Currently, I construct "maps" by simply making a C++ source file and start writing:

```cpp
SHADOWENGINE ShadowEngine(&settings);

SPRITE_SETTINGS sset;
MODEL_SETTINGS mset;

sset.Name = "Sprite1";
sset.Pivot = TOPLEFT;
sset.Source = "sprite1.png";
sset.Type = STATIC;
sset.Movable = true;
sset.SoundSet = "sprite1.wav"

ShadowEngine->Sprites->Load(sset);

sset.Name = "Sprite2"
sset.Source = "sprite2.png";
sset.Parent = "Sprite1";
sset.Type = ANIMATED;
sset.Frames = 16;
sset.Interval = 1000;
sset.Position = D3DXVECTOR(0.0f, (ShadowEngine->Resolution->Height/2), 0.0f);

ShadowEngine->Sprites->Load(sset);

mset.Source = "character.sx";
mset.Collision = false;
mset.Type = DYNAMIC;

ShadowEngine->Models->Load(mset);
//Etc..
```

What I'd like to be able to do, is to create map files that are instead loaded into the engine, without having to write them into the executable. That way, I can make changes to the maps without having to recompile every damn time.

```cpp
SHADOWENGINE ShadowEngine(&settings);

ShadowEngine->InitializeMap("Map1.sm");
```

The only way I can think of is to make it read the file as text and then just parse the information, but it sounds like such a hassle.

Am I thinking the wrong way?
What should I do?

Wouldn't mind an explanation on how others do it, like Warcraft III, Starcraft, Age of Empires, Heroes of Might and Magic...

Would **really** appreciate some help on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not thinking the wrong way, loading your map data is definitely desirable. The most common prebuilt solutions are Protocol Buffers and Lua. If you don't already know Lua I would use protocol buffers, as it directly solves your problem, whereas Lua is a scripting language which is flexible enough to do what you need done.

Some people write their data as XML, but this is only a partial solution as XML is just a markup language. After loading the XML you'll have a DOM tree to parse.

[Google's CPP Protobuf Tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/cpptutorial.html)

Comment: Not to mention XML takes up a bunch of space. I've read a little about LUA and I suppose this is as good of a time as any to start learning, now that I've found a use for it. Thanks! I'll be over at [LUA Headquarters](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html) if anyone needs me ;)